# C: Write the address of a pointer on the standard output?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-address

How can I write the address of an pointer to the standard output using only the `write()` function. (similarly to the `%p` flag in the `printf()` function.)

I'm not allowed to use anything else than 'write' 'malloc' and 'free'.

Comment: *Only* the write function? You can't use something like `sprintf` to prepare the output?

Comment: Have you tried using `snprintf`? If yes, how did it go? If not, try that! If you can't use it, then you need to use some other (possible your own) function to convert a number to a string, but the principle is the same.

Comment: I'm not allowed to use anything else than `write` `malloc` and `free`.

Comment: That is implementtion defined. It cannot be done in a portable way. But you should have a look at `uintptr_t` for the first step. The rest is mostly integer arithmetics which you should have learned in your course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are trying to recode `printf`, you probably want to implement `%p`. Use the following steps:

- retrieve the value of the pointer from the argument va_list.
- convert that pointer to a `uintptr_t` or whatever unsigned integer type is appropriate for the pointer size on your target architecture.
- convert this integer to a string in hexadecimal format with a `0x` prefix, as for the `%#x` format.
- write the resulting string to the output file.

Comment: `uintptr_t` is the only type guaranteed to hold a pointer value. But anything else than assigning to/from the same `void *` (and by that indirectly other pointer types) is implementation-specific. As is the output format (he could print the bytes as characters as well).

Answer (score 2):

If you have a pointer variable like `char *p;` then you can write it using

```
write(filedescriptor, &p, sizeof(p));
```

Just like writing any other variable really.

If you want to write it as a string, then you need to format it as a string first, and write the string:

```
char pstr[sizeof(p) * 2 + 2 + 1]; // Each byte of the pointer is two hexadecimal character, plus a potential 0x, plus terminator
snprintf(pstr, sizeof(pstr), "%p", (void *) p);
write(filedescriptor, pstr, strlen(pstr));
```

You *can* write it as a string using *only* `write`, by treating the pointer as a normal integer value, and loop over all the bytes in the pointer variable and use either modulo and division or shifting to get each byte, and then use byte masking and shifting to get each nibble of each byte, and convert it to a character to write. It might be easier to do if you copy the pointer value over to an array of bytes to iterate over as then you don't have to do the modulo/division, only the masking and shifting to get each nibble.

---

***But*** with that said, I'm really curious about *why* you would want something like that? Because you can't save a pointer in a file and use it in another program (or even the same program but run as a new process), you can't send it over a pipe or a socket to another process.

Comment: `sizeof(p) * 2 + 1` might not be enough room for the textual representation of the pointer value produced by `%p`. A `0x` prefix is often present, and the standard leaves a lot of room for implementations to make architecture specific choices. You should declare a buffer with a larger size and use `snprintf` to avoid a potential buffer overflow.

Comment: @chqrlie You're right, I should have been using `snprintf` from the start.

Comment: As I just mentioned in the edit of my question, I'm not allowed to use anything else than write malloc and free. And the first solution you gave `write(filedescriptor, &p, sizeof(p));` doesn't seem to work. I'm getting `�'���` as output.

Comment: @CosminSerdean Already added a solution to that (the paragraph under the `snprintf` example).

Comment: That seems confusing may you add an example please?

Comment: @CosminSerdean A variable (no matter the type) is stored in memory as a sequential series of bytes, just like an array of bytes. So if you treat it as a series of bytes it's easy to iterate over to get each byte. Then to get the top four bits (nibble) of a byte you shift it right four steps, and those four bits will then give you a value between `0` and `15`  which corresponds to a hexadecimal digit, and can easily be used as an index into a 16-character array to translate the number to a character. Then you take the four low bits and mask (using `&`) the top bits and you have the next digit.

Comment: @CosminSerdean Now with that information, go try something yourself. ***Experiment!*** :)

Comment: "Just like writing any other variable really" is bogus -- writing unmarshalled binaries is often a recipe for disaster. As to the "why": For the same reasons `%p`  was introduced in later iterations of the C standard.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider: While I fully agree about using proper marshalling, pointers are not portable by their very nature, nor can they be normally preserved between different runs of a program (or sent from one to the other).

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider And that's kind of the point with the whole "But..." paragraph.